# How to interpret the model_max_len attribute of the PreTrainedTokenizer object in Huggingface Transformers

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I've been trying to check the maximum length allowed by emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT, and after these lines of code:

```
model_name = "emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer
```

I've obtained the following:

```
PreTrainedTokenizerFast(name_or_path='emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT', vocab_size=28996, model_max_len=1000000000000000019884624838656, is_fast=True, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right', special_tokens={'unk_token': '[UNK]', 'sep_token': '[SEP]', 'pad_token': '[PAD]', 'cls_token': '[CLS]', 'mask_token': '[MASK]'})
```

Is that true? Is the max length of the model (in the number of tokens, as it says [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.11.0/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer)) that high? Then, how am I supposed to interpret that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/16998) thread addresses a similar question.
According to that this is due to an error caused due to the max length not being specified in the tokenizer config file (`tokenizer_config.json`).
according to [this](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/16998#issuecomment-1184522342), a solution would be to modify the config file.

The [docs](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.11.0/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer) also say this

> If no value is provided, will default to VERY_LARGE_INTEGER (int(1e30))

you can find similar issues related to [this](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues?q=1000000000000000019884624838656)